# Python list can't delete first item

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a list of text files from a directory so I can extract key data from them, however, the list my function returns also contains a list of the file pathways as the first item of the list. I've tried del full_text[0] which didn't work, as well as any other value, and also the remove function. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?
Thanks

```
import glob

file_paths = []
file_paths.extend(glob.glob("C:\Users\12342255\PycharmProjects\Sequence      diagrams\*"))
matching_txt = [s for s in file_paths if ".txt" in s]
print matching_txt
full_text = []
def fulltext():
    for file in matching_txt:
        f = open(file, "r")
        ftext = f.read()
        all_seqs = ftext.split("title ")
        print all_seqs
full_text.append(fulltext())
print full_text
```

Comment: You're not actually returning anything from the `fulltext()` function. Therefore, `full_text` remains empty.

Comment: Use the slice format to copy part of the list. `full_text = full_text[1:]`

Comment: @RobertR:  `fulltext()` returns `None` by default, therefore the list `full_text` will have one element which a reference to `None`

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to delete the first element?  `del` should work, please post the failing code.

Comment: If you are finally printing the `full_list`, you should get `[None]` as the code stands now. What is the output?

Comment: @CPanda He should also get content of the files as he's printing out `all_seqs`. That may be where he got confused. I'm assuming he meant to append `all_seqs` to some list and return it.

Comment: When I print full_text I get the pathways at the top (which I don't want) but I also get a full list of the text files which is exactly what I'm looking for followed by [none] as the last item

Comment: Also if I append all_seqs to my list I don't get the text documents, I just get the pathways and [ ]

Comment: The reason you get the `.txt` files printed out is because you print out `matching_txt` (which contains the file names) on the sixth line in your shown code. The reason you're getting the content printed out is because of the `print all_seqs`. And finally the reason you get `[None]` printed out is because you print out `full_text`, but it has nothing in it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to get rid of the first element - `full_text[1:]`. This creates a copy of the list. Otherwise, you can `full_text.pop(0)` and resume using `full_text`

Answer (score -1):

I see at least two ways to do so:

1) you can create a new list from first position e.g. `newList = oldList[1:]`

2) use remove method - `full_text.remove(full_text[0])`